# "Builds on Heroku-16 will not be possible from June 1st, 2021. Please upgrade the stack of your app as soon as possible" when pushing to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to push my app and got the following message:

```
Building source:
Your app is using the Heroku-16 stack, which has been end-of-life since May 1st, 2021.
    Builds on Heroku-16 will not be possible from June 1st, 2021.
    Please upgrade the stack of your app as soon as possible:
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
    Heroku-16 EOL FAQ: https://help.heroku.com/0S5P41DC/heroku-16-end-of-life-faq
    THIS IS A ONE-OFF NOTICE. THE NEXT DEPLOY WILL FUNCTION WITHOUT INTERRUPTION.
    The next warning of this kind will occur in: 1 day(s).
```

I'm pretty nervous about just running this and breaking the app. Why doesn't Heroku just have an automatic migration? Why not support this older version? Does anyone know of the best (and most simple) migration method to Heroku-20?

Comment: Try it on your staging app. You do have a staging app, right?

Comment: "Why doesn't Heroku just have an automatic migration?"—would you really want your infrastructure to unpredictably change? Upgrading the stack _is_ the "automatic" option, you just need to decide when to do it.